# Not able to set DataSet Type in Data Labeling MLStudio

Tags: dataset, azure-machine-learning-service

Not able to set DataSet Type in Data Labeling project  MLStudio.

Default dataset file type is displaying always. I want to work with panda_dataframe. How can I set dataset to tabuler dataset while creating the dataset.

Also how can I change the Filedataset to Tabular datasetI want to apply pandas_dataframe. but it is not available with file dataset.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-2d5c0c116404> in <module>
     10 
     11 
---> 12 pd_fill = dsfill.to_pandas_dataframe(file_handling_option=FileHandlingOption.DOWNLOAD, target_path='./download/', overwrite_download=True)
     13 pd_fill

AttributeError: 'FileDataset' object has no attribute 'to_pandas_dataframe'
```

[image]

Comment: In Data Labeling the Web file datasets, open datasets and tabular datasets currently not supported.If the datasets is from azure storage, ensure that the data set and its data store configuration are valid for it to be supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can create dataset from dataset UI instead of labeling UI. There you can choose dataset type to be tabular.